# Exception in AnimationUtils.loadAnimation() (sometimes)

Tags: android, android-animation, android-handler

I am getting a null pointer exception in the line given in code below. The problem is, the exception occurs randomly. Many times it just works but sometimes it throws an exception (say 5% of times). Any help would be appreciated.

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.anim.dialog_main_show_amination);  //Exception in this line
        fabAddDeliveryBoy.startAnimation(animation);
        fabAddDeliveryBoy.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     }
}, 500);
```

Comment: what is the exception ?

Comment: Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: thrown by the getActivity(), you should check if getActivity is not null, like for the context, before creating the animation

Comment: @Hacketo But just above this handler I have `JoolehApplication jApp = (JoolehApplication)getActivity().getApplicationContext();` If the `getActivity()` is throwing null, it should be null too.

Comment: the handler is delayed by 500 ms right ?

Comment: Yes. The handler is delayed by 500ms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your handler is not tied to your fragment lifecycle. The handler messages can fire even after the fragment is detached from its activity, and `getActivity()` will return null.

As a quick fix, you can put your `Runnable` in a variable and clear the handler in e.g. `onDestroyView()`:

```
handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
```

For a more elegant solution, consider making the delay a part of the animation itself.

Comment: Thank you so much. It looks like a valid solution but I can't exactly tell because there is no way to test. It just happens randomly. I have accepted the answer and I will ask again here if the problem persists.